# Incorrect syntax near some keyword in c# / sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following code snippet :-

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string idd = Session["senderefirstname"].ToString();

    Query = " create table '"+ idd +"' (  senderid varchar(90) , recipientid     varchar(90),senderimage varchar(90), senderfirstname varchar(90), senderlastname varchar(90),    message varchar(max) ) ";
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds); 
    Response.Redirect("newmessage.aspx");
}
```

but m getting the error is

> "Incorrect syntax near 'noah'"

`noah` is the string stored in `session["senderfirstname"]` I'm getting this error. Can anyone guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use single quotes when you use `CREATE TABLE`.

Just use `create table "+ idd +"`

Take a look at syntax from [`CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

But more important, I don't understand your code at all. I don't think you need to use `SqlDataAdapter` or `DataSet` because your query does not return anything.

Just execute your query with [`SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method like;

```
Query = " create table "+ idd +"(senderid varchar(90), recipientid varchar(90),senderimage varchar(90), senderfirstname varchar(90), senderlastname varchar(90),message varchar(max)) ";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Query = " create table "+ idd +" (  senderid varchar(90) , recipientid     varchar(90),senderimage varchar(90), senderfirstname varchar(90), senderlastname varchar(90),    message varchar(max) ) ";
```

I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Query= "create table "+ idd +"(senderid varchar(90),recipientid varchar(90),senderimage varchar(90), senderfirstname varchar(90), senderlastname varchar(90),message varchar(max) ) ";
```